# How can i get the single result using DQL in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want to get the last user profile . But i am not able to do that in DQL.
I have this code

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();

$dql = "SELECT p  FROM AcmeBundle:UserProfile p 
        WHERE p.user_id = :user_id 
        ORDER BY p.createdAt DESC ";

$allProfiles = $em->createQuery($dql)
                  ->setParameter('user_id', $user_id)
                  ->setMaxResults(5)
                  ->getResult();

return $allProfiles;
```

It returns all the profiles.

If i use getSingleResult() then it says result not unique

Comment: did you tried by changing `setMaxResult(1)` ?

Comment: i tried result(1) as well but that also retured array not single object

Comment: setMaxResults(1) works fine...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
                $allProfiles = $em->createQuery($dql)
                                ->setParameter('user_id',$user_id)
                                ->setMaxResults(1)
                                ->getResult();
                return $allProfiles[0];
```

Comment: What happend if $allProfiles is void?

Comment: Then use this: `if (empty($allProfiles)===true) { return null } else { return allProfiles[0]; } ` instead of last row

Answer (score 63):

The right method is:

```
$singleProfile = $em->createQuery($dql)
                    ->setParameter('user_id',$user_id)
                    ->getSingleResult();
```

To prevent error then no results try this:

```
$singleProfile = $em->createQuery($dql)
                    ->setParameter('user_id',$user_id)
                    ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Comment: If the query is in a field other than the ID and the query returns more than one record, `getOneOrNullResult` returns an error. Is there a function that returns only the first, for example?

Comment: The first example returns 
`More than one result was found for query although one row or none was expected.` when there is more than one row.